# node file system access error on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, fs

I have a simple code that saves the image selected to the file system using express fs

```
exports.upload = function(req, res) {

  var photoInfo = req.body,
      file      = req.files.file,
      fileType  = file.type.slice(6);

  //attaching the fileType to photoInfo because fileType is part of req.files, not part of req.body
  photoInfo.fileType = fileType;

  var newPhoto = new Photo(photoInfo);

  Photo.create(newPhoto, function(err, insertedPhotoInfo){
    if (err) throw err;

    var photoId = insertedPhotoInfo._id;

    //create directory if it does not exist already
    fs.exists(__directory, function(exists) {
      if (!exists) {
        fs.mkdir(__directory, function(err, data){
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      }
    });

    //create the file with the unique id created by mongo as its name
    // http://www.hacksparrow.com/handle-file-uploads-in-express-node-js.html 
    // get the temporary location of the file
    var tmpPath = file.path;
    // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory
    // var targetPath = './uploads/' + req.files.file.name;
    // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
    fs.rename(tmpPath, __directory + '/' + photoId + '.' + fileType, function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
      // var reader = new FileReader();
      // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
      fs.unlink(tmpPath, function() {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(insertedPhotoInfo);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

this works perfectly on localhost, but once I deploy to heroku, I get ENOENT, open error. It seems to be losing access to the fs. I presume it is because heroku only has ephemeral file system.

Would there be any work around for this? or would I need to set up a separate vm/static file server?

Comment: Where is the ENOENT thrown? `ephemeral` means it won't persist on restarts I believe, so I don't think it's your problem. But I see in code that first you are renaming a file and then removing it. Well after it's rename, the path shouldn't exist anymore! Try this: `touch a; mv a b; rm a;`. It won't work obviously.

Comment: I removed the unlink part, I still get ENOENT error. I do not know which line is giving me the error because this is running on heroku server not on my node.